# How can I filter and return array of patients whose birthDate's year is between 1960 and 1965 (inclusive)?

Tags: angular

Code that I have tried

```js
  getPatientsResource() : Observable<any[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get(environment.queryURI + '/Patient',
      { headers: this.getHeaders() }).pipe(
        map(res => res['entry'].filter(res => {           
          let currentYear = new Date(res.resource.birthDate).getFullYear(); console.log(new Date(res.resource.birthDate).getFullYear())
          new Date(res.resource.birthDate).getFullYear() > 1959 && new Date(res.resource.birthDate).getFullYear() < 1973
        }))
      )
  }
```

Comment: and? do you get any error? or wrong result?

Comment: my array is blank instead of few records.

Comment: did you debug? what is the value coming from the server? Specifically, what is in `res.entry.resource.birthDate`? you have to spell it out in the question. In fact, I would suggest you create an array with string values, and practice with it until you get a good grasp of how `Date()` and `getFullYear()` functions work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: you are not returning anything from your filter function ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what's wrong without seeing the response, but you need to check the date format you are using matches a format that can be parsed. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#several_ways_to_create_a_date_object)

Here's an example that works [on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-playground-l7w8x7)

```
of(['1959-12-17', '1960-12-17', '1963-12-17', '1965-12-17', '1967-12-17'])
      .pipe(
        tap(items => {
          console.log('before');
          console.log(items);
        }),
        map(arr =>
          arr.filter(n => {
            const year = new Date(n).getFullYear();
            return year >= 1960 && year <= 1965;
          })
        ),
        tap(items => {
          console.log('after');
          console.log(items);
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
res['entry'].filter(item => 
  new Date(item.resource.birthDate).getFullYear() > 1960 && 
  new Date(item.resource.birthDate).getFullYear() <= 1965
);
```

Comment: it should also be ">= 1960", no?

Comment: If you want to include 1960, then yes. I thought you didnt.